# custom field in admin columns

Tags: custom-field, admin, columns

Im trying to understand how to get  the custom field incr_number into admin columns. However im failing to understand and im googling but not finding a direct answer.

It cant be that hard surly?

```
   <?php


   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   /* WooThemes supportpress Custom Post Types Init */
   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  function woo_supportpress_post_types_init() {

    add_option('tickets_slug', 'tickets');

 register_post_type( 'ticket',
    array(
        'label' => __( 'Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Tickets', 'woothemes' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
            'all_items'   => __( 'All Tickets', 'woothemes' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'woothemes' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit', 'woothemes' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Tickets', 'woothemes' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Ticket', 'woothemes' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Tickets', 'woothemes' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No tickets found', 'woothemes' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No tickets found in trash', 'woothemes' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Tickets', 'woothemes' ),
        ),
        'description' => __( 'This is where you can create new tickets for your site. Tickets can also be created from the front-end.', 'woothemes' ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => get_option('tickets_slug'), 'with_front' => false ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'tickets',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'author', 'comments' ),
    )
);



register_taxonomy( 'ticket_status',
    array('ticket'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Ticket Statuses', 'woothemes'),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket Status', 'woothemes'),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Ticket Statuses', 'woothemes'),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Ticket Statuses', 'woothemes'),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Ticket Status', 'woothemes'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ticket Status:', 'woothemes'),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Ticket Status', 'woothemes'),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Ticket Status', 'woothemes'),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Ticket Status', 'woothemes'),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Ticket Status', 'woothemes')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'ticket-status', 'with_front' => false ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy( 'ticket_priority',
    array('ticket'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Ticket Priorities', 'woothemes'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket Priority', 'woothemes'),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Ticket Priorities', 'woothemes'),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Ticket Priorities', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Ticket Priority', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ticket Priority:', 'woothemes'),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Ticket Priority', 'woothemes'),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Ticket Priority', 'woothemes'),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Ticket Priority', 'woothemes'),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Ticket Priority', 'woothemes')
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'ticket-priority', 'with_front' => false ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy( 'ticket_type',
    array('ticket'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Ticket Types', 'woothemes'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket Type', 'woothemes'),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Ticket Types', 'woothemes'),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Ticket Types', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Ticket Type', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ticket Type:', 'woothemes'),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Ticket Type', 'woothemes'),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Ticket Type', 'woothemes'),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Ticket Type', 'woothemes'),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Ticket Type', 'woothemes')
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'ticket-type', 'with_front' => false ),
    )
);

register_taxonomy( 'ticket_tags',
    array('ticket'),
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Ticket Tags', 'woothemes'),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Ticket Tags', 'woothemes'),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Ticket Tags', 'woothemes'),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Ticket Tags', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Ticket Tag', 'woothemes'),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ticket Tag:', 'woothemes'),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Ticket Tag', 'woothemes'),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Ticket Tag', 'woothemes'),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Ticket Tag', 'woothemes'),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Ticket Tag', 'woothemes')
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'ticket-tag' ),
    )
);


  }  

  add_action( 'init', 'woo_supportpress_post_types_init', 0 );


 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /* Admin columns for post types */
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

 function woo_supportpress_ticket_columns($old_columns){

$columns = array(

'cb' => '<input type=\"checkbox\" />',
'title' => __('Ticket Title', 'woothemes'),
'incr_number' => __('Ticket ID', 'woothemes'),
'status' => __('Status', 'woothemes'),
'priority' => __('Priority', 'woothemes'),
'type' => __('Type', 'woothemes'),
'author' => __('Submitted by', 'woothemes'),
'assigned' => __('Assigned to', 'woothemes'),
'comments' => $old_columns["comments"],
'date' => __('Date', 'woothemes'),
);

return $columns;

 }

add_action( 'custom_woo_supportpress_ticket_columns',    'custom_woo_supportpress_ticket_columns', 10, 2 );

function custom_woo_supportpress_ticket_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;

switch( $column ) {

    /* If displaying the 'incr_number' column. */
    case 'incr_number' :

        /* Get the post meta. */
        $incr_number = get_post_meta($post_id, 'incr_number', true );



        break;

}
 }

 add_filter('manage_edit-ticket_columns', 'woo_supportpress_ticket_columns');

 function woo_supportpress_ticket_custom_columns($column) {
global $post;

$ticket_details = woo_supportpress_get_ticket_details( $post->ID );

switch ($column) {
    case "status" :
        echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_status', '', ', ','');
    break;
    case "priority" :
        echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_priority', '', ', ','');
    break;
    case "type" :
        echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_type', '', ', ','');
    break;
    case "assigned" :

        if ($ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID>0) :
            $link = get_author_posts_url( $ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID );
        else :
            $link = add_query_arg('assigned_to', '0', get_post_type_archive_link('ticket'));
        endif;

        echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name.'</a>';

    break;
    case "id" :
        echo '#'.$post->ID;
    break;
}
 }
add_action('manage_ticket_posts_custom_column', 'woo_supportpress_ticket_custom_columns', 2);
```

Comment: can you clarify exactly where this code is? i.e. is it inside a function that you're calling from a hook?

Comment: Its called by the function.php `require_once locate_template('/lib/ticket-post-type.php');        // Custom Post Types`

Comment: try reading and working your way through [this tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types), you should be able to find the relevant functions in your theme and add in your extra column.

Comment: Hi I tried that one earlier, but maybe i was doing it wrong?

Comment: is the first part of your code (where you define the array) inside a function, and is that function called by a hook? in your question it's just floating around in the middle of nowehere...

Comment: thats the whole page above

Comment: Don't suppose you worked out how to submit other types of text custom fields via the Supportpress create ticket page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing everything from the comment downwards with this. Basically you seemed to have a function in there that wasn't getting called, and you need to add the `case "incr_number"` test to the `woo_supportpress_ticket_custom_columns` function:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Admin columns for post types */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function woo_supportpress_ticket_columns( $old_columns ){

    $columns = array(
        'cb'          => '<input type=\"checkbox\" />',
        'title'       => __('Ticket Title', 'woothemes'),
        'incr_number' => __('Ticket ID', 'woothemes'),
        'status'      => __('Status', 'woothemes'),
        'priority'    => __('Priority', 'woothemes'),
        'type'        => __('Type', 'woothemes'),
        'author'      => __('Submitted by', 'woothemes'),
        'assigned'    => __('Assigned to', 'woothemes'),
        'comments'    => $old_columns["comments"],
        'date'        => __('Date', 'woothemes'),
        );

    return $columns;

}

add_filter('manage_edit-ticket_columns', 'woo_supportpress_ticket_columns');

function woo_supportpress_ticket_custom_columns( $column ) {

    global $post;

    $ticket_details = woo_supportpress_get_ticket_details( $post->ID );

    switch ($column) {
        case "incr_number" :
            echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'incr_number', true );
        break;
        case "status" :
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_status', '', ', ','');
        break;
        case "priority" :
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_priority', '', ', ','');
        break;
        case "type" :
            echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticket_type', '', ', ','');
        break;
        case "assigned" :
            if ($ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID>0) :
                $link = get_author_posts_url( $ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID );
            else :
                $link = add_query_arg('assigned_to', '0', get_post_type_archive_link('ticket'));
            endif;
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name.'</a>';
        break;
        case "id" :
            echo '#'.$post->ID;
        break;
    }
}

add_action('manage_ticket_posts_custom_column', 'woo_supportpress_ticket_custom_columns', 2);
```

Comment: hi thanks for that but it made no difference, incr_number still isn't been populated. it displays fine in loops so i know it works just cant figure out why not on the back end

Comment: ` echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'incr_number', true );` THIS FIXES THE PROBLEM! Thanks Simon Blackbourn your a life saver!

Comment: glad to help! well spotted with the typo - i've now updated my code with your correction.